# Why I cannot set a cell style without getting a +, it also doesn't apply faithfully the strokes on the cells

Tags: adobe-indesign, style

I have indesign cs6 and a table with 2 rows and 5 cols and some horizontal and vertical merges. If I try to define the cell style from the cell style menu I cannot set the inner strokes. Because of this I do in this way:

- Create the table like I've said before
- Select the 2 rows and it will appear a box divided in 4 parts with inner edges.
- Here I select the inner edges and set some way
- Then the outter edges and set another way
- I click on the cell style while selecting the cells and I click "Redefine style"

After sometime it appears a + after the name style, and I cannot click the "Redefine style" again. Don't know why... This is the first problem.

Now I also have another table with cells styled this way and keeps a border to the right that wasn't supposed to be there.

Do you know anyway to work clearly with cells and border and don't get the + after the style without changing anything...?

thanks (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to achieve a table with outer strokes set with one parameters (say thickness), and inner strokes with other parameters.

The best way to achieve that is to use a Table Style, not a Cell Style. Table styles allow setting table stroke (outer), row strokes and column strokes (inner) separately as well as to alternate them.

The reason you get a Style+ situation is that a Cell Style applies to every single cell, not the group of cells (that's why there is no Inner Stroke option in the Cell Style - a single cell cannot have inner strokes). In your particular situation you select several cells each having different stokes on different sides - InDesign does not clearly understand which of those cells you want to become a sample for the style (all of them are different!), so to retain the appearence it assigns a + to each cell.

By the way, to clear any +'s from any selection you can Alt+click on the style name including [none] for cell styles.

Comment: well, for simplicity I didn't said that there were headers and body cells. I also use table style, but the problem was to set the border between the headers rows and between the headers and body, as this is not managed by the table style. Now, how do I set a inner style in cell style in order to change that cell style and update all cell instances in the document?

Comment: Oh, so you have multiple header rows and you want a thicker stroke around the whole header. I'm afraid there is no "style-perfect" solution for that besides creating several cell styles - for upper header row, bottom header row, and spanning header cells (where you will have both top and bottom strokes thicker)

Comment: oh, thanks anyway! We've managed to do a white 0.25mm border in the header inner and outter. Also the outter border in the body are white. This will give us a 0.25mm white indentation, and keeps a clean style and the look it's also minimalistic. thanks for your answer (: